# Could not resolve peer dependency: React Native Firebase App and Firestore

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-firebase

I've been trying to create an app with react native firebase and am having some problems. I'm getting another error ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77889458/cant-solve-execution-failed-for-task-react-native-firebase-appcompiledebugj)) and in looking around online it seems like maybe it's the result of conflicting dependencies with the packages. So I tried updating @react-native-firebase/app and @react-native-firebase/firestore and I'm getting these warnings/errors "Could not resolve peer dependency"

It looks like Firestore is expecting app to be version 18.7.3 and it actually is version 18.8.0. So I guess I would have to downgrade? I'm really not sure what to do here.

Here's the error message for npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app:

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: ez_dollar_v0.2@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: @react-native-firebase/app@18.8.0
npm WARN node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm WARN   @react-native-firebase/app@"^18.8.0" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @react-native-firebase/app@"18.7.3" from @react-native-firebase/auth@18.7.3
npm WARN node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth
npm WARN   @react-native-firebase/auth@"^18.7.3" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: ez_dollar_v0.2@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: @react-native-firebase/app@18.8.0
npm WARN node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm WARN   @react-native-firebase/app@"^18.8.0" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @react-native-firebase/app@"18.7.3" from @react-native-firebase/firestore@18.7.3
npm WARN node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore
npm WARN   @react-native-firebase/firestore@"^18.7.3" from the root project

added 2 packages, and audited 1185 packages in 5s

66 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

5 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.


And here is the error message for npm install --save @react-native-firebase/firestore:
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @react-native-firebase/auth@18.7.3
npm ERR! Found: @react-native-firebase/app@18.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm ERR!   @react-native-firebase/app@"^18.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @react-native-firebase/app@"18.8.0" from @react-native-firebase/firestore@18.8.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore
npm ERR!     @react-native-firebase/firestore@"18.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @react-native-firebase/app@"18.7.3" from @react-native-firebase/auth@18.7.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth
npm ERR!   @react-native-firebase/auth@"^18.7.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @react-native-firebase/app@18.7.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm ERR!   peer @react-native-firebase/app@"18.7.3" from @react-native-firebase/auth@18.7.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth
npm ERR!     @react-native-firebase/auth@"^18.7.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/benfirstenberg/.npm/_logs/2024-01-27T16_59_24_206Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/benfirstenberg/.npm/_logs/2024-01-27T16_59_24_206Z-debug-0.log
```

All I've tried so far was to add "@latest" to the installs, that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/firestore --legacy-peer-deps
```